# COPY INTO snowflake table not loading data - No errors

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

As part of the Snowflake WebUI Essentials course, I'm trying to load data from 'WEIGHT.TXT' on AWS S3 bucket into a Snowflake DB table.

```sql
select * from weight_ingest

> Result: 0 rows
```

```sql
list @S3TESTBKT/W

> Result:1 
> s3://my-s3-tstbkt/WEIGHT.txt  509814  6e66e0c954a0dfe2c5d9638004a98912 Tue, 17 Dec 2019 14:52:52 GMT
```

```sql
COPY INTO WEIGHT_INGEST
FROM @S3TESTBKT/W
FILES = 'WEIGHT.TXT'
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME=USDA_FILE_FORMAT)

> Result: Copy executed with 0 files processed.
```

Can someone please help me resolve this? Thanks in advance.

**Further Information:**

S3 Object URL: `https://my-s3-tstbkt.s3.amazonaws.com/WEIGHT.txt` (I'm able to open the file contents in a browser)

Path to file: `s3://my-s3-tstbkt/WEIGHT.txt`

**File Format Definition:**

```sql
ALTER FILE FORMAT "USDA_NUTRIENT_STDREF"."PUBLIC".USDA_FILE_FORMAT 
SET COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' 
FIELD_DELIMITER = '^' 
RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' 
SKIP_HEADER = 0 
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = 'NONE' 
TRIM_SPACE = FALSE 
ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE 
ESCAPE = 'NONE' 
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' 
DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
NULL_IF = ('\\N');
```

**Stage Definition:**

````sql
ALTER STAGE "USDA_NUTRIENT_STDREF"."PUBLIC"."S3TESTBKT" 
SET URL = 's3://my-s3-tstbkt';
```
````

Answer (score 1):

I believe issue is with your copy command. Try following steps:

Execute list command to get list of files:

```
List @S3TESTBKT
```

if your source file appear here just make sure folder name in your copy command.

```
COPY INTO WEIGHT_INGEST
FROM @S3TESTBKT/
FILES = ('WEIGHT.txt')
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = USDA_FILE_FORMAT);
```

Comment: Thank you Sriga for responding, it worked!!  <br/>Observed 2 things missed in my cmd <br/> Brackets around 'WEIGHT.txt' was missing and instead of 'WEIGHT.txt', I mentioned 'WEIGHT.TXT' (all caps) <br/> Ignore the stage name @S3TESTBKT/W in my cmd, earlier I tried @S3TESTBKT also but didn't work due to the 2 differences mentioned above. <br/> I didn't like the fact that we have to mention brackets around file name, anyways Thank you again!

Comment: Another thing I noticed is if I rerun the COPY cmd for the same file, the cmd succeeds but logs an error that File was loaded before. This is a good feature from accidental reload of a given file. I guess it makes sure that it does chksum before erring out like this. Otherwise, assume that a daily file with same name everyday but different data has to be loaded into the table, it shouldn't fail saying that this file was loaded earlier.

Comment: @Prashanth Yes Snowflake maintain meta data for the load file, So even if you submitted copy command again it won't copy the data, until you are forcing it.